# Continuously update ggplot with new data is too slow

Tags: r, loops, plot, ggplot2

I would like to plot some values that I calculate continously. I prepared a litte code example to explain this problem. Every time, I create a new value, I would like to insert this into my plot and update the diagram.

```
library('ggplot2')

x <- seq(1,20)
y <- rnorm(20)

g <- qplot(x, y)

for(i in 1:50){
    y <- c(y[2:20], rnorm(1))
    print(g)
}
```

So the example works but it flickers tremendously, every time a new diagram is created, it gets cleared (a white screen) and after some time and only for a short period the diagram appears.

If I use only the standard `plot(x,y)` it works perfect but I would like to apply ggplot. Or do I have to change the parameters of X11() or maybe there is a faster device, or maybe ggplot has some kind of update function (only updating the points)?

Comment: `ggplot2` is much slower than base graphics; there isn't much you can do about it. Every time you update the plot with new data, it performs some calculations (e.g train the scales) and builds the plot, which takes time. In base graphics, provided you know the full scales in advance, you can simply add new points to the plot, a much cheaper operation.

Comment: Yab, but isn't there a possibility, that redraws the diagram after the calculation and thus, immediately draws without cleaning and leaving this white screen???

Comment: interactive devices vary in performance; the fastest, I believe, is Acinonyx, but it remains largely experimental.

Comment: @andre maybe you can get a look  at `animation` package